# Wayfinder: Display the Resources that are "under" another Resource with Wayfinder

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, wayfinder

I am developing a website that has a main navigation on top and then some different navigations in the right sidebar ([here](http://(https://www.dev.stephan-fuhrer.ch/versicherungsrecht/)).

I am recalling them with Wayfinder and now I would like to display them in "Tree" structure in the sidebar.

For example for the Resource AVB(39) I have 2 under resources: "RESOURCE UNDER RESOURCE AVB #1" and "RESOURCE UNDER RESOURCE AVB #2".

How can I display them in a "Tree" structure? Something Like

AVB

- RESOURCE UNDER RESOURCE AVB #1
- RESOURCE UNDER RESOURCE AVB #2

This is my actual code:

```
[[!Wayfinder? &startId=`5` &level=`0`]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
[[Wayfinder? &startId=`[[*parent]]` ]]
```

Or if you are a few level deep then check out the UltimateParent snippet, which will allow you got a certain amount of levels up.
https://modx.com/extras/package/ultimateparent

For example

```
[[Wayfinder? &startId=`[[UltimateParent? &topLevel=`2`]]` ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run UltimateParent uncached like this: `[[!UltimateParent]]`